# Dynamically load nib for iPhone/iPad within view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, universal

I have converted an iPhone application using the wizard like thing in XCode into a universal app.

It builds fine but obviously looks a bit rubbish in some areas :)

I need to load nibs according to which device is being used. I dont wish to create my view controllers using `initWithNib` as I already have code to create the controllers with some data (`initWithMyLovelyData`) which doesnt do anything to do with nib loading.

I know to find out the device you use `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` so I tried overriding the `initWithNibName` within the actual view controllers themselves, assuming they get called internally somehow. But it's not working as I guess I am unsure of the syntax.

I have tried

```
if(ipad..) self = [super initWithNibName:@"MyIpadNib" bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
```

And that doesnt work :/

EDIT - I know I have massively edited this, made my question a bit more specific after doing some more research - apologies!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

EDIT: @Adam's answer below is the correct answer.

To determine which nib to load, do the following, and scrap your `initWithMyLovelyData` method and use a property to set the data. You should be able to easily move all your init code into the property setter method.

```
MyViewController *viewController;

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ipadNIB" bundle:nil];
} else {
    viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"iphoneNIB" bundle:nil];
}

viewController.myLovelyData = someData;
```

Comment: Sorry to dig up old(er) posts but: This is not working for me. Any ideas?

Comment: @Linuxmint What problem are you having?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306346/trouble-with-loading-a-separate-xib-for-ipad-or-iphone

Comment: FWIW, @adam's answer is the correct one and much better than this.

Comment: Since the nib name is just one of two strings, and the rest of the VC allocation/initialization is the same, you can shorten the code by having just one call to alloc/init the VC, using an NSString variable which is either set to one nib name or the other.

Answer (score 77):

Actually, Apple does all this automatically, just name your NIB files:

```
MyViewController~iphone.xib // iPhone
MyViewController~ipad.xib // iPad
```

and load your view controller with the smallest amount of code:

```
[[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; // Apple will take care of everything
```

Comment: if you use this statement: [MyViewController alloc] init];  in above example instead, is it doing exactly the same thing?  or is it doing something slightly different?

Comment: I expect "init" does nothing. If you want it to load a NIB, you need to call initWithNib - or else manually load a NIB from the bundle

Comment: [[MyViewController alloc] init] is exactly the same as [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil nibBundle:nil]  This is mentioned in the UIViewController.h file: "If you subclass UIViewController, you must call the super implementation of this
  method, even if you aren't using a NIB.  (As a convenience, the default init method will do this for you,
  and specify nil for both of this methods arguments.)"

Comment: Where is this documented? The documentation of "nibName" in UIViewController specifies how the nib name is resolved when none is provided, but does not seem to mention this approach.

Comment: IIRC this feature is only documented in one place - the bits about "loading resources / using Bundles", which many people never happen to read. Technically, nibName etc re-uses the underlying bundle/resource-loading system - so Apple assumes you'll read this elsewhere and remember it.

Comment: Just want to add that the bits of the documentation describing how "iOS Supports Device-Specific Resources" can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: This is definitely the better answer. No reason to switch on interface idiom. No reason to copy/paste the init code. No reason to type the nib name twice (or at all).

Comment: `initWithNibName:nibBundle` is the designated initializer for `UIViewController`, so even if it wasn't explicitly documented anywhere, you would know that calling `init` on a view controller would eventually call through to `initWithNibName:nibBundle`.

Comment: Apple skipped the designated initializers specifically in UIViewController / UIView since iOS version 2.0. Anything loaded from NIBs used initWithCoder/awakeFromNib combo instead (bypassing their own - documented! - designated init'r). So ... you can't trust "designated initializers" in UIKit, sadly

Comment: In what scenario will name of the xib play a role ? In my case it works regardless of how I name xib file. I guess framework simple relies of value in `customClass` attribute. Is that correct, @Adam?

Answer (score 2):

I just put these two methods in a class called IPadHelper, and use the addIPadSuffixWhenOnIPad method to conditionally pick between two nibs depending on platform

```
+ (BOOL)isIPad{
    if (kCFCoreFoundationVersionNumber >= kCFCoreFoundationVersionNumber_iPhoneOS_3_2){
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}

+ (NSString *)addIPadSuffixWhenOnIPad:(NSString *)resourceName{
    if([IPadHelper isIPad]){
        return [resourceName stringByAppendingString:@"-iPad"];
    }
    else {
        return resourceName;
    }   
}
```

see here h[ttp://cocoawithlove.com/2010/07/tips-tricks-for-conditional-ios3-ios32.html](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/07/tips-tricks-for-conditional-ios3-ios32.html) for more explanation of the first method...

Comment: Compiler said that this is wrong, because Class methods should return objects (id). So If think it will be better to add this to C file.

Answer (score 2):

You can have your cake and eat it too.  Just add a method that wraps initWithNibName:bundle: and adds your myLovelyData parameter:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil  myLovelyData:(id)data
{
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) 
    {
        // Custom initialization using myLovelyData
        //
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be better to create C file.
FileHelper.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
BOOL isIPad();
NSString *addIPadSuffixWhenOnIPad(NSString *resourceName);
```

FileHelper.m

```
#import "FileHelper.h"
BOOL isIPad() {
    if (kCFCoreFoundationVersionNumber >= kCFCoreFoundationVersionNumber_iPhoneOS_3_2) {
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}

NSString *addIPadSuffixWhenOnIPad(NSString *resourceName) {
    if(isIPad()) {
        return [resourceName stringByAppendingString:@"-iPad"];
    }
    else {
        return resourceName;
    }   
}
```