# My xib nib files don't load for ipad version, why?

Tags: iphone, ipad, nib, xib

I have converted my project to support iPad (universal).  I have changed it so the MainWindow loads MainWindow-iPad (it does), and that in turn calls it's sub-view controller (it does as well).

In my sub-view controllers code, it instantiates other view controllers and loads them.  But only the iPhone version is loading.

So my question is, is the app supposed to automatically look for '-iPad' extension on nib files and load them appropriately, or do I have to make a change in code myself for each nib, like this post:

[Dynamically load nib for iPhone/iPad within view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052288/dynamically-load-nib-for-iphone-ipad-within-view-controller)

If so, its strange that the application can't automatically display the appropriate xib file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app will not automatically look for the -iPad extension on XIB files. It does for you MainWindow-iPad only because there's a setting in the info.plist that determines this.