# use self with if condition before super.init(nibName:)

Tags: xcode, swift, if-statement, initialization, self

I would like to use self with an if condition in `init()` method... (before the `super.init()`).

Here is my example I can't use (self before super.init) :

```
init()
{
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        if self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .Regular
        {
            super.init(nibName: ProductDetailsIdentifier, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        }
        else
        {
            super.init(nibName: ProductDetailsIdentifierIphone, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        }
    }
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    super.init(coder : aDecoder)
}
```

Comment: Do you perhaps have an [X/Y question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?. What was the original problem you are trying to solve? It seems like you want to conditionally load a nib for the view, is this correct?

Comment: Is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052288/dynamically-load-nib-for-iphone-ipad-within-view-controller/9603879#9603879) helpful to you?

Comment: The object needs to be initialized first by super class and then you can do your custom initialization

Comment: @Kevin Yes I would like to make an if-statement, to load different xib depending on the size clas

Comment: What is the "size class"? Is it your own custom class? What does it do? What's it's purpose? Does it **have** to be a property in your view controller or can you move it somewhere where the view controller can access it before being done with initialization?

Comment: @Kevin Thanks Kevin !!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052288/dynamically-load-nib-for-iphone-ipad-within-view-controller/9603879#9603879 is perfect